# How do I set my age and location on my user page?

Tags: support, profile-page, users, mobile-web

At the bottom of every question, answer, or comment there is a name of a user who posted it. Clicking on his name allows you to see some information about him (for example his age, location, etc.).

How do I post information about myself so that when my page is clicked, my age and location will be there?

I am using an Android.

Comment: [Clicky](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/231805). You can then decide to save across all SE networks or just the one you are currently on.

Comment: Folks _more than a few_ people can't find this initially, please remember that you're _used_ to our interface before down voting a perfectly legitimate support question. </soapbox>

Comment: While I did not downvote, its kinda hard to answer a support question when the most *essential* detail is missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an Android browser that supports switching to "Desktop View", then click on it. For example on Samsung Galaxy phones you can find that here:

> [image]

If your browser doesn't support this, or it doesn't work, then most mobile sites (including Stack Overflow) has the option to switch to the full site:

> [image]

On the full site, the edit button on the profile page works just fine:

> [image]

Comment: I don't think he's using the app. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: that's not the SE app, it's the default browser on an S3

Comment: Hmm... so switching to "Desktop view" cause the browser to behave like a desktop browser. Smart!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Yes, but it depends on the browser. Samsung's browser is smart enough, so when you switch to desktop view it tries to suppress everything that would tell the page that you're on a mobile browser (no mobile headers are sent, viewport size is set to at least 1000px, etc.). Some other browsers will only suppress the mobile headers, but not change the size of the viewport meaning responsive sites will still appear as mobile. In this case you can either use another browser, or hope the site has a "full site" button.

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to your [profile-page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/231805/isaac-d).
2. Click [edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/edit/231805)
   [image]
3. Edit away :)
   [image]

Comment: Thank you! I just noticed what I was doing wrong. I am using an android. Therefore not the whole page was displayed so I couldn't see the edit button because  my screen there is no edit button. I will try going on with my pc.

Comment: @IsaacD You can also do it from a mobile device by clicking "full site" link in the footer. When done, click "mobile" in the footer to get back to the mobile view which is more fitting for mobile devices, thus missing certain features.