# Allow linking (suggested) edits to one comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits, review, suggested-edits

As the feature-request [Show the post's comments on the “Suggested Edits” review interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150142/146482) elaborates on, some suggested edits seem too radical without the context of comments they are based on.

I fully endorse this request and would like to take it one step further:

Add the option to "suggest* edit based on this comment" next to comments, which would specifically highlight that comment below the suggested edit, such that edits that otherwise would be deemed "too radical" at first sight can be put into a better context. On approval, said comment would also become linked-to by the revision comment.

Since it makes sense to upvote such a comment due to it providing information justifying an edit, that link could replace the flagging-flag (which is anyway hidden after an upvote) with the edit-pen that indicate edited comments, like so:

> [image: mockup of this functionality]

(mockup based on a [true](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2726595) [story](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228687/jq-grid-beforecheckvalues-return-type#comment26762895_18228687), coming to cinemas never)

In fact, for the editor's convenience, the clicked-on base-comment might also be added to the bottom of the post and preselected (e.g. for one-key deletion or conversion to a quote)

---

`*` The "suggest" would not be shown for users with the required edit privilege (<2k rep or OP), yet this option would allow to link an edit to a helpful comment and include aforementioned preselect-insertion of the comment at the post's bottom for convenience

Comment: The reason I propose having to upvote a comment first is a) it is relevant (though it might be flagged obsolete after the edit got approved) and b) one-line comments would take to much space if the pen were also shown in addition to the other two icons...

Comment: Alternatively, when in edit mode the comments could have checkboxes added indicating "This comment is relevant to the edit", allowing an even better overview if e.g. multiple comments are merged into one edit

Comment: Nice maze you made there.

Comment: @KeesSonnema You're the first to escape it alive, congratulations :D (any suggestions for improvement are welcome)

Answer (score 6):

> "suggest" would not be shown for users with the required edit privilege

As an editor with full privileges, I would be more than happy if it would be also shown to me and even somehow auto-magically linked-to (quoted-in / reflected-in...) edit summary in post [revisions history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/revisions-list/info).

I did probably [several hundreds edits](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat?tab=activity&sort=revisions) having summaries prefixed with phrase **"clarification copied into post from comments"** and I find it quite cumbersome to manually add the link to "source comment" to these.

Actually, I often skip adding that link, which naturally makes it only harder to trace and verify the source that caused my edit.

---

It gets even worse when I copy from the comment but forget to add the canned summary. For a most recent example at MSO, take a look at [revision 4 in this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/193930/revisions) and try to guess [why the hell](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193930/how-do-i-set-my-age-and-location-on-my-user-page#comment608521_193931) I dared to add *"I am using an Android"* to a question from a guy who's a total stranger to me?

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVbF4.png]

<sub>For the sake of completeness, in this case I forgot to add summary because discovery of the comment was to me a striking revelation that turned a low quality zero-effort question into a perfectly reasonable [support request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/support/info).</sub>

Comment: Precisely - oh I was formulating that awkwardly, what I meant was for 2k-users the tooltip would read "edit based on this comment", without the incorrect "suggest"