# Use a comment as a reason for an edit

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

One of the purposes of comments is to provide feedback on a post, and this request is specific to the comments that are feedback on ways to improve the post.

When an edit is being made to a post, the editor could select a comment, and have it be linked to that edit.  Maybe have it be the edit summary, maybe have it linked via a new method.  This linkage would be used to document that the edit is taking care of the improvement requested in the comment.

Once the edit is complete, this should then remove the comment (and possibly comments replying to it), closing the loop on the comment improving the post.  It would also provide a new way for comment threads to be cleaned up.

Comment: I wonder if there would be a way to use an @address in the edit explanation that would ping the commenter to look at the changes and remind them to remove their comment if it was addressed. If it were really fancy, it could maybe tie the comment into the edit explanation so that it's visible in the history even after the edit is deleted... But even something like "Edited at ____ request from a comment to add more detail".

Comment: See also: ["_optimization - linking comments to edits_"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279228/997587).

Answer (score 1):

I am having difficulty envisioning an intuitive UI for this scenario —  an author receives notification of a comment (among many) and somehow is directed to select that comment (or multiple in a conversation) specifying  it is an *improvement* and then goes to edit the post causing the comment to disappear automatically.

That sounds very abuse-able ("author selects comments to disappear"); and I'm not sure there's a real-world UI metaphor to guide users through that type of workflow.

I like the thought process — get rid of comment when they are no longer needed — but I'm afraid we are a long way off from that type of comment-processing automation without introducing a really large learning curve to something that is supposed to be a lightweight feature.

Comment: No, I think it's the other way around... Say an OP is asked by someone in a comment "can you add more detail to your question?"... usually, the only way to let someone know that you've added the requested detail is to leave a comment saying something along the lines of "edited as requested @person".  I think this is requesting making it possible to connect an edit by the OP to a comment that requests it.

Comment: [UI for this feature was suggested in duplicate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/194277/165773)