# optimization - linking comments to edits

Tags: feature-request, comments, edits

It has become quite a common occurrence now that I edit a post, flag a comment for removal citing the 'obsolete' reason, and almost all of those flags get marked as helpful, and the comment removed.

Why not automate this process?

Assume a scenario in which I edit a post, mark some related comments which are linked to the edit and are addressed. If the edit is approved (the users approving also check whether or not the comments are correctly addressed and unmark any that aren't) the comments are automatically removed by the Community user.

(Of course, this will only be valid for reviewed edits, not automatic ones like the OP doing an edit to their own post. Otherwise we'll have unaddressed comments getting auto-deleted.)

Since the whole purpose of a comment is to suggest corrections of some errors in a post, this seems logical. Then there would be no need for this redundant 'obsolete' reason, and moderators will be free to focus on removing offensive/spam/off-topic comments, questions and answers.

Has this been proposed before? If yes, what happened?

Comment: related: [Allow linking (suggested) edits to one comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194277/allow-linking-suggested-edits-to-one-comment)

Comment: @gnat Are you saying users will often forget linking the comments? I think that's just a question of habit. Once a habit forms, the problem will go away.

Comment: The user posting the comment is in my opinion the sole that can remove the comment or not. (or a mod in case of abuse) In your approach, I would maybe just link a number on comment, to reference to which edit number it was wrote. (As I can show you example of when I ask a user a simple clarification, and get answered something else.)

Comment: I am saying that option to link an edit to comment would be useful, even without subsequent removal

Comment: @yagmoth555 Someone replying is irrelevant - comments would otherwise work as normal. In the above case, nothing would happen.

Comment: replying? in my example when I mean "answered", a edit was done to answer me.

Comment: @yagmoth555 Then your comment is obsolete, provided the necessary part has been included in the edit to the question, or the errors have been fixed. Reviewers can always 'Approve and Edit' to ensure that.

Comment: in my example the OP answer me something else, how my comment is obsolete ? review queue for comment? on the site iam on we dont have enougth to review only the close queue. a big burden that would add.

Comment: @yagmoth555, ah, I see. Yes, this policy should only be valid for reviewed edits, not automatic ones like the OP editing their own posts.