# Give editors and edit-reviewers visible reminders to flag NLN where appropriate

Tags: feature-request, edits, comment-flags

##### Proposal

- In the edit UI for non-suggested edits, add a reminder near the finish button to flag [NLN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420) on comments where appropriate.
- In the review UI for suggested edits, for reviewers who are about to give a "final approval", in a visible location (for example, near the submit button), give a reminder to flag NLN on comments where appropriate. "Final approval" includes final "OK", or "improve edit" or "reject and improve edit".

  - <sup><sub>Unlike [this one, which proposes a new flag type for flagging *before the edit*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146708/997587)</sub></sup>.
  - It may go hand in hand with this other feature request: [Show the post's comments on the "Suggested Edits" review interface](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/150142/997587)

The reminder message can link to [the MSE FAQ guide for moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237978/997587).

The reminder can be omitted for users who don't have the flag privilege. (Or, [we could allow post authors to flag NLN on comments on their posts even without 15 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383485/997587))

Ideally, comments that are truly no longer needed would get removed as fast as possible. Benefits: Less clutter, less possible confusion to readers, etc.

There are plenty of other related feature requests I'd really like to see happen. The point of *this* proposal is to take what could be the **simplest** first step possible (implementation-wise).

##### Synergy with Another Feature Request

See [this feature request that "*Obsolete comment flags should notify the original commenter in advance of moderators*"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183753/997587).

These two feature requests would complement each other to tighten the feedback loop workflow without requiring the commentor to follow the post, or the editor thinking they should create reply-ping comments like "thanks I edited" (for example, see [this SEDE query of SO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1664981), which has over 46K such comments within 100 characters each, and [this SEDE query of MSO](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackoverflow/query/1664313)).

In the case of canned comments, I propose that this would instead notify the reviewer who gave that review, and potentially also those who upvoted the canned comment, since [more NLN flags are needed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17365/997587) in proportion to number of comment upvotes. (I am not sure if this is easily implementable.)

Also related is this feature request to [Make community comment moderation a more public process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213694/997587)

##### Topically Related Posts

- The [explanation of the suggested edits review queue on the meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/997587), and the [fuller guide on reviewing that queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/155539/997587).

  - I edited them to add reminders to flag NLN where appropriate, but the review queue UI doesn't link to those pages, so they aren't very visible unless you really go look for them (speaking from experience).
- Others related to comment cleanup, but they did not focus on the edit feedback loop: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135464/997587), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281649/997587), [this one has a lot of good discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180325/997587).
- Ideally, we wouldn't have as much need for a feedback workflow and posters would get feedback while writing their post (see the "Ask Wizard" posts and other ones related to reducing manual-work of teaching new users).
- [This other feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279228/997587) is basically <sup><sub>(oversimplifying here)</sub></sup> a request for a dedicated/glorified UI/UX to do this. Unlike that one, this is just asking for some "road signs", which I think is much easier to implement, and a good first step (20%-of-the-effort, 80%-of-the-results kind of thing).
- If you're hungry for even more feature requests in a similar vein, here's the search query I used when doing my research: `is:question [feature-request] [comments] [edits] -[status-completed]`.

Comment: Bonus fun: if this is implemented, it will help prevent candidates for r/nocontext such as [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20221125054942/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59631363/pass-variable-to-class-for-use-by-init/59631512#comment105425260_59631512).